# How do I generate the location (row and column) of a specific value in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, vlookup

I made a schedule in Google Sheets (days of the week as columns, time as rows, student names within the chart). I want to make an additional chart restating the data by student name that will update if I move the students in chart 1. I would love it to report day and time, but would settle for any sort of location information whatsoever.

I have tried combinations of VLOOKUP, QUERY, and Match. The problem is that it only works as long as the student stays in the same location. If I move it to a different cell I get an error as it only works for a single row or column.

The closest I have gotten is that I can make a hyperlink to the cell. When you hover over the link it gives the cell location, but I don't know if it is possible to make the cell location the name.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I5ZMOa8dEcVhYmbT-LDaqX-I7s5L5cH1QR8xVH4dVGQ/edit#gid=1364833249

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your samples of input and expected output in your question in text format, Links/image are not encouraged, thank you.

Comment: Google Sheets have a lot of useful features and built-in functions like VLOOKUP, FILTER, QUERY, etc. and could be extended by using Google Apps Scripts and add-ons. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: [access denied](https://i.imgur.com/DGXVL72.png), Please share the sheet with [Everyone with the link](https://i.imgur.com/Oh4SUnW.gifv)

Comment: Its open now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 Schedule!B2:F&"×"&Schedule!B1:F1&"×"&Schedule!A2:A), "×"), {2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula( 
 SORTN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Schedule!B1:F1&"^_~"&Schedule!B2:F6&"^_~"&Schedule!A2:A6),"^_~"),
 COUNTA( INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Schedule!B1:F1&"^_~"&Schedule!B2:F6&"^_~"&Schedule!A2:A6),"^_~"), ,3)),,3,1))
```

[image]